# How to limit characters per line in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I want to limit the number of characters per line in CKEditor (django-ckeditor, to be precise) and have it add a line break `<br>` whenever it wraps a long line, but I haven't found a way to do it without having to write JavaScript code for it.

This is my configuration in `settings.py`:

```py
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'colorButton_colors': '000000,0000FF,FFFF00,FF0000,FF00FF,00FFFF,008000,FFFFFF',
        'colorButton_enableAutomatic': False,
        'colorButton_enableMore': False,
        'extraPlugins': 'sharedspace',
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            ['Italic', 'Underline'],
            {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
        ],
        'sharedSpaces': {
            'top': 'top',
            'bottom': 'bottom',
        },
        'removePlugins': ['elementspath', 'resize', 'magicline'],
        'enterMode': 2,
        'shiftEnterMode': 2,
        'height': 150,
        'width': 300,
    },
}
```

I first tried setting the `rows` and `cols` attribute for the widget when defining the form, following the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54035412/limit-rows-in-html5-textarea), but that doesn't really work with CKEditor. Tried it like this:

`forms.py`

```py
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    # ...Some fields...
    form_text = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget(attrs={'rows': 10, 'cols': 40, 'wrap': 'hard}))
```

This actually sets the attributes of the textarea successfully (I can see them when I inspect the element), but then, when typing to the editor, the text goes beyond 40 characters per line and the wrapping does not add a `<br>`. I guess because I'm not typing to the textarea anymore, but to the embedded HTML document's body.

I then went to do this "manually" with JavaScript/jQuery, with this code:

**NOTE:** You can skip this code and jump to the bold part below. I am adding it just to show what I've tried and in case it is relevant and someone has a suggestion.

```js
// Get the editor content in a variable, as an array of text lines.
var tempText = $('iframe').contents().find('body')[0].innerHTML.split('<br>');

var currentLine;
var lineWrapped = false;
var i = 0;

// Check every single line
for (i; i < tempText.length; i++) {

    // The first 'replace' gets rid of zero-width spaces and the second gets rid of <span> tags that are not part of the text but that CKEditor uses to add the colors.
    // This way I can see the actual length of the line.
    // There might be other non-printing characters CKEditor adds, but this is okay for the test.
    currentLine = tempText[i].replace(/\u200B/g, '').replace(/\<[^<]*>/g, '')

    
    if (currentLine.length > 40) {
        // Get all the words and their indexes.
        var words = [...currentLine.matchAll(/\S+/g)];

        // If there is more than one word, then there is a place to add the <br>.
        if (words.length > 1) {
            // This pattern is to find the index of the last word in the actual line (with the <span> tags and everything.
            // $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex is used to automatically escape metacharacters.
            var subMatch = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(words[words.length-1][0], 'g');
            // This array is used in case the last word appears more than once.
            var matchArray = [...temptText[i].matchAll(subMatch)];
            // This is the index at which the actual last word appears in the line; it's used to add the <br>.
            var actualIndex = matchArray[matchArray.length-1].index;
            // Inserting the <br> to break the line before the word that made it too long.
            tempText[i] = tempText[i].substring(0, actualIndex) + '<br>' + tempText[i].substring(actualIndex, temptext[i].length);
        }
      
        // Flag used to indicate that this happened.
        lineWrapped = true;
    }
    
}

// Return the text to the original form it was found in the editor.
tempText = tempText.join('<br>');

// If a line was wrapped, modify the content of the editor with the new <br>.
if (lineWrapped) {
    $('iframe').contents().find('body')[0].innerHTML = tempText;

}
```

This code did the job for the first tests. You can see there are things it doesn't consider, like the case in which a long line consists of only one "word." This is because I stopped working on it because **I realized that, every time the content of the editor is modified, the cursor changes its position back to the first character of the first word of the first line. This way, the user can't continue typing the word they were typing.**

Maybe I could find a way to set the cursor's position where it should be, but I still need to know if there is a simpler way to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: My question would be why you want this in the first place? Why insert line breaks into flowing text?

Comment: Because my app requires that to process the text, it needs to know exactly where all lines end. I need that to behave exactly as if the user pressed RETURN.

Comment: Again, I don't understand why you need this. Your requirement seems very weird, given that you can just let the computer break lines at any given width when displaying the text. Still, if you do need this, my suggestion would be to insert the line breaks *after* the user has submitted the text.

Comment: Let me put your suggestion in my own words to see if I understood it. I would control the line length with the editor's width and not the character count, then, when the user submits the form, I would add the line breaks. Did I understand correctly? If so, is this method reliable for when the window is resized? I really need this to be done with characters per line.

Comment: If you use a fixed width font you should be able to set the editor to the exact width that breaks the lines accordingly. Later, you simply use the same width to display the text. Or you break the lines manually based on the character count.

Comment: Great. I'll try with the width and update here.